# Javascript keeps defaulting when other scripts are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some JavaScript on a site I am building that I just can't get to not default when another script is used. Interestingly not all of the javascripts on the page cause the issue.

This is the script that I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.verdana').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','verdana');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.arial').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','arial');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.tahoma').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','tahoma');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.times').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','times');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.copperplatebold').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','copperplatebold');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('swiss721').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','swiss721');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.baskerville').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','baskerville');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.oldenglish').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','oldenglish');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });


    $('.timesnewroman').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','timesnewroman');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.castellar').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','castellar');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.calibri').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','calibri');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.scriptmtbold').click(function(e) {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','scriptmtbold');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });

    $('.lucidacal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);  
    });

    // select font in dropdown list to change font-family of #changeMe
    $('select').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Default font"){
            $('#changeMe').css('font-family',"");
        } else {
            $('#changeMe').css('font-family',$(this).val());
        }
    }); 
    e.preventDefault(e);  
});
```

Anyway I have tried putting "e.preventDefault(e);" in many places but no joy.

And another possible clue is that it seems to be my javascripts that also use drop down menus for selection that do it.

As always you're all stars for helping out! Thanks in advance!

HTML Elements that default the above script

```
<div style = "position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 490px;">
<select style="width: 150px;" id = "fonty">
<option selected="selected">Select Your Font....</option>
<option>Times New Roman</option>
<option>Verdana</option>
<option>Copper Plate Bold</option>
<option>Swiss721</option>
<option>Baskerville</option>
<option>OldEnglish</option>
<option>Castellar</option>
<option>Calibri</option>
<option>ScriptMTBold</option>
<option>LucidaCal</option>

<div style = "position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 440px;" >    
<select id="selectcolor" name="selectcolor" style="width: 150px;">
                    <option value="null">Select Text Colour...</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="darkblue">Dark Blue</option>
                    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                    <option value="seagreen">Sea Green</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="darkgreen">Dark Green</option>
                    <option value="bergundy">Bergundy</option>
                    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
                    <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
                    <option value="mustard">mustard</option>
                    <option value="purple">Purple</option>

 </select>
 </div>


<div style = "position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 540px;">
<select id="category-navbar" name="category-navbar" style="width: 150px;">
<option value="">Motif Set One...</option>
<option value="H">motif 1</option>
<option value="rs">motif 2</option>
<option value="2">motif 3</option>
<option value="y">motif 4</option>
<option value="f">motif 5</option>
<option value="j">motif 6</option>
<option value="m">motif 7</option>
<option value="-,">motif 8</option>
<option value="[">motif 9</option>
<option value=";">motif 10</option>
<option value="V">motif 11</option>
<option value="N">motif 12</option>
<option value="R">motif 13</option>
<option value="]">motif 14</option>
<option value="F">motif 15</option>
<option value="t">motif 16</option>
<option value="">none...</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and the div for the text that I am affecting:

```
<!--The address div-->     
<div class="selectcolor" style = "position: absolute; left: 425px; top: 360px;"id="changeMe">....please add you address using the box on the left</div>
```

Comment: Typically, `.preventDefault()` is supposed to be the _first_ line inside the handler, not the last.  See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thanks Sparky so does that mean that the individual prevent defaults should take care of it or do you mean I need to add it before the font selections?

Comment: You don't have anything with the classes you're listening for clicks on. You probably want to listen to when the `fonty` select's value changes, and change the font based on that

Comment: Thanks Colin DeClue I think  I understand. So the issue probably is that it is listening for any clicks not just the one from the fonty div?

Comment: The first line within each handler function, means the very first line... that would be before _anything_ else.

Answer (score 0):

**After you posted your HTML**

You're not being specific with your "select" selector. You have a number of  elements, doing different things - only one of which holds values to font families.

Also, you haven't closed the first opening  tag in your HTML.

---

**First**

It could be a script error being thrown. You have a stray e.preventDefault() at the bottom which isn't a part of any listener.

**Second**

If this is in an external script (it's own .js file) - make sure you DON'T have the  tags in it. If the content is dynamic - Make sure that's considered when this script is loaded/executed.

Comment: He wrapped the entire code block in `$(document).ready()` so actually he can include the script wherever he wants. You're absolutely correct about the dynamic HTML though.

Comment: @apparatix You're spot on. I missed that.

Comment: Not an external .js all in page. Its baffling me for sure!

Answer (score 0):

For you click event handler for `swiss721` you are selecting an element with the tag name `swiss721`, not a class name:

```
$('swiss721').click(function(e) { // This line
    $('#changeMe').css('font-family','swiss721');
    e.preventDefault();  
});
```

You should add a period before the selector:

```
$('.swiss721').click(function (e) {
```

Additionally, the method `preventDefault()` does not take in any arguments, but you are passing one to it in a few cases at the end.

Lastly, you have an extraneous `e.preventDefault()` after your `select` handler.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out the '.swiss721' issue I hadn't spotted that! I have made that change and I have taken out the stray preventDefault but the un wanted behaviour is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.verdana')` won't work because there is no element with a class 'verdana' (at least in your HTML you posted).

You have to listen for the `change` event on the `select` element (with id `fonty`) which contains all the fonts.

```
$("#fonty").change(function(event) {
    var selectedFont = $(this).val();
    if (selectedFont == "Verdana") {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','verdana');
    }
    else if (selectedFont == "Copper Plate Bold") {
        $('#changeMe').css('font-family','copperplatebold');
    }
    // ......
});
```

---

*Enhancement suggestion*:

you can shrink your javascript code if you set the value of each `<option>` so that it can be used as the font you pass to `$('#changeMe').css("font-family", ...)`

HMTL:

```
<select style="width: 150px;" id = "fonty">
    <option selected="selected">Select Your Font....</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="copperplatebold">Copper Plate Bold</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    ...
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#fonty").change(function(event) {
    var selectedFont = $(this).val();
    $('#changeMe').css('font-family', selectedFont);
});
```